Working with multiple input data (image, float64 value) on InceptionV3
def inceptionV3(reshaped_images, scores, y, unique_y_values, percentage):  


 X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(reshaped_images, y, test_size=1-percentage, random_state=42)
 X_2_train, X_2_test = train_test_split(scores, test_size=1-percentage, random_state=42)

# Convert target class names (authors) to numerical labels
 label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
 label_encoder.fit(unique_y_values)
 y_train_encoded = label_encoder.transform(y_train)
 y_test_encoded = label_encoder.transform(y_test)

 # One-hot encode target labels
 y_train_encoded = to_categorical(y_train_encoded)
 y_test_encoded = to_categorical(y_test_encoded)


 # Load pre-trained inceptionV3 model
 base_model = InceptionV3(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)


 # Add custom classification head
 x = base_model.output

 print('Shape of Output :', x.shape)  # --> Shape of Output : (None, None, None, 2048)

 # Add an additional input layer
 extra_input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,), dtype = 'float64')

 #x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)

 # x = Concatenate()([base_model.output, extra_input_broadcasted])
 x = Concatenate(axis=-1)([base_model.output, extra_input])


 predictions = Dense(len(y_train_encoded[0]), activation='softmax')(x) # for the size of classes
 model = Model(inputs=[base_model.input, extra_input], outputs=predictions)
 model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
 model.fit([np.array(X_train), np.array(X_2_train)], np.array(y_train_encoded), batch_size=64, epochs=5)

 # Make predictions
 y_pred_proba  = model.predict(np.array(X_test), verbose = 0)

I am getting the following error :
ValueError: The total size of the tensor must be unchanged. Received: input_shape=(512,), target_shape=(1, 1, 280, 512)
I want to add a second input of shape 1 in a inceptionv3 with this
extra_input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,), dtype = 'float64')
'Scores' is an array of float64 numbers. Each row has only 1 value.
